# How to authenticate using Authorization Header Token in api requests in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, bearer-token, get-request

I'm about to request a get call to retrieve data from my server. I have enabled authorization to have a Bearer token in most of the requests. How can I include that when I request for something from the server? (what am I doing wrong here? Please help me out.)

For an example, I'm having a file named Categories.service.ts which is going to get categories from the server.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CategoriesService {

  private _url: string = "http://ifsstudents.educationhost.cloud/v2/categories/list";

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  private token: string="Bearer eyJ0eXA....";

  getCategories():Observable<ICategory[]>{
    let header = new HttpHeaders().set(
      "Authorization",this.token
    );

    return this.http.get<ICategory[]>(this._url,{headers:header});
  }
}
```

I have tested using Postman with the Bearer token, It's working without any issues. 
[image]

here's the error log
[image]

Comment: any errors? you don't seem to check for errors

Comment: Check for cors errors in the console. If it works in postman but not in angular, this is usually the cause. If not, show more of your code (subscribe, error, handler) and screenshots for network requests/responses (header and data) from your browser

Comment: wait I'll update the question @David

Comment: This is the cross site origin issue for that check your config file and add the enable core entry.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a established server with a test-app ?, if yes, proxy-config approach may work for you

Comment: how can I do that? would u be kind enough to tell me how? @CharanjeetSingh

Comment: yes. @SupunDeSilva what do u mean by proxy-config approach?

Comment: @M.Sachintha please follow this URL might help you "https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/"

Comment: Added an as an answer as I do not have adequate real-estate in the comments. Let me know if it works

Comment: @M.Sachintha did it work ?

Comment: no it didn't @SupunDeSilva ... I'm sorry I was busy at work .. I'll try again and let you know. I think there's a problem with my server too.. I included all the CORSE headers also.

Comment: The idea was to skip having CORS headers and use an intermediary server as a proxy. Is this api available to public ?

Answer (score 1):

Change `CategoriesService` as follows

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CategoriesService {

private _url: string = "/api/categories/list";

constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

private token: string="Bearer eyJ0eXA....";

getCategories():Observable<ICategory[]>{
    let header = new HttpHeaders().set(
    "Authorization",this.token
    );

    return this.http.get<ICategory[]>(this._url,{headers:header});
}
}
```

in your root folder (same level as `src` folder) create a file called `proxy.conf.json` with the following content

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://ifsstudents.educationhost.cloud/v2",
    "secure": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Start the app with

`ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json -o`

**Keep an eye on the console to see if the route transformation happen correctly**
you should see something like follows

`[HPM] Rewriting path from "/api/categories/list" to "/categories/list"
[HPM] GET /api/categories/list ~> http://ifsstudents.educationhost.cloud/v2`

**If you intend to Productionize this, you need to enable appropriate CORS rules in `ifsstudents.educationhost.cloud`**